# running at dkms status

Tags: kernel

When we check the dkms status it shows the following message

```
rtl8723de, 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414: added
rtlwifi-new, 0.6, 4.15.0-46-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
```

Comment: You have two problems. The rtl8723de dkms module is added, but not installed. The rtlwifi-new has been installed before, but there are now two different versions on your system. Edit your question and show me `ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/updates/dkms`. Tell us more about the problem that you're trying to solve, and what you've done to try and solve it.